# Camels, Sheep, Lambs and Cows

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

Find the value of the camel.

Easy enough right?

[image]

*this is not my puzzle*

Comment: Eh? Well, for a good one, I once gave 13 shekels an old shifl and my own baleboste. Oy vey!

Comment: What the hell is wrong with the people on this site

Comment: @TylerJohnson the issue with this question is it is a math problem not a math puzzle.  The [on topic page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) links to [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2784/12760) meta post explaining the difference.  Math problems are considered off-topic hence the down votes.

Comment: @gtwebb thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fairly simple substitution, and I don't see any real trick

> From the first and fourth equations; sheep - goat = 25,
> and from the second and third equations, plugging that in; 500 - goat = 480 + 2 goats, so a goat is 6 and 2/3, so a camel is 593 and 1/3

Or, if we obey Order of Operations a bit more strictly, and don't allow our eyes to group things logically

> The third equation is now (Camel-Sheep)+Goat leading to
> Sheep = 45, Goat = 20, and Camel = 480

Comment: Not the intended answer, but it works. The actual answer has a solution without the need of fractions

Comment: Haha nah I'm kidding, you're right